# Can Windows XP do FTP over SSH from network places?

Tags: windows-xp, ssh, ftp

I'd like to setup a FTP over SSH connection within my network places so my applications can access those files as if it were another mapped drive. Is this possible under windows XP?

Comment: Do you really mean "FTP over SSH"? Or do you actually mean "SFTP"?

Comment: I do mean SFTP - Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I'm guessing from your answers (because you've all listed third party apps) that Windows XP does not offer native support for SFTP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can do with SFTP, then the free (for personal use) [Tunnelier](http://www.bitvise.com/tunnelier) has an [FTP-to-SFTP](http://www.bitvise.com/tunnelier#ftp-bridge) bridge that might be useful. With the bridge active you can for example create a regular mapped network drive in windows.

> Tunnelier incorporates an FTP-to-SFTP bridge which performs translation between the FTP and SFTP protocols, allowing any FTP client application to connect securely to an SFTP server through Tunnelier. Both active mode and passive mode FTP data connections are supported, as well as restarted transfers, directory listings and other features. All FTP clients should be able to list directories and transfer files across Tunnelier's FTP-to-SFTP bridge, including integrated clients in applications such as DreamWeaver, GUI clients such as BulletProof FTP, and command line clients such as the default ftp.exe client accompanying Windows. If an FTP client you use fails to work with Tunnelier's FTP-to-SFTP bridge, let us know.
>
> See [Accessing an SFTP Server with an FTP Client](http://www.bitvise.com/ftp-bridge) for more information about the FTP bridge.

Answer (score 1):

If what you really mean is "SFTP", then [WebDrive](http://www.southrivertech.com/products/webdrive/index.html) can do it.